# RosAria doesn't update after certain time?

Tags: python, ros

I have a robot (*Pioneer 3-AT*) with distance sensors that I wan't to drive around autonomously.

**What am I using?**

- Pioneer 3-AT (Robot with wheels and a bunch of sensors and stuff, see: http://www.mobilerobots.com/ResearchRobots/P3AT.aspx)
- ROS (tool to let scripts interact over network by publishing and subscribing to "topics", see: http://www.ros.org/)
- RosAria (this connects the ROS network and Pioneer, it takes data published to the /RosAria/cmd_vel topic and moves the robot accordingly, see: http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA)

**This is the setup:**

The sensors are connected to an Arduino Mega that is connected to the robot over serial port (*/dev/ttyS0*), after the Arduino gets the sensors data it sends them over the serial port to the robot, where a python scripts takes this data and uploads it to the ROS network, this upload automatically gets detected by RosAria which in turn moves the robot.

**In short:**

Sensors ---> Arduino ---> Robot (Python Script) --(ROS)-> RosAria

The python script also turns the sensor data into commands for the robot (left, right, ...)

**This setup works ... for a certain amount of time**

The robot automatically moves forward after the script is started.
If I hold something in front of the sensors it changes direction. NOTICE: This is whilst the robot is connected to my PC using Ethernet. However, after I disconnect the Ethernet cable it continues to work for a short amount of time.

**This bug is strange**

It stops working in a very strange way.
I found this out whilst debugging:

- the robot continues to move forward but does not react to sensor input.
  (both things are handled in the same script, at the same place)
- the sensors output the data correctly
- the script doesn't output any errors
- the connection to RosAria is still running
- RosAria receives the movement commands

According to what I found out, it should work perfectly (since it does so when connected to the ethernet), but weirdly enough, after a few meters it changes from avoiding obstacles very well to going full on berserk and just ramming everything out of its way.

What could be wrong?

Comment: where do you run the rosmaster? 
I had a similar problem when I had the rosmaster(roscore) running on another computer. If there was something wrong with the connection to the rosmaster the robot just went amok.

Comment: the rosmaster is run directly on the robot, I initially wanted to run it on the PC but communication over ROS only works in one direction (Robot->PC) not the other way around. Maybe I should have mentioned this

Comment: for the other way around you need to set ROS_IP and not just ROS_MASTER_URI. 
And for the problem, can you not connect a screen or sth. to the robots computer and check what is happening and how movement commands are constructed?

Comment: i have already tried setting ROS_IP and ROS_MASTER_URI, however the problem seems to be that the computer and robot are in different subnets which i cannot fix currently. Connecting a monitor is going to be difficult since the error only occurs when the robot is entirely disconnected and moves away from his original position. I dont think i understand what you mean with "how movement commands are constructed"? they use two geometry_msgs.Vector3 variables if thats what you mean

Comment: if the connection to rosmaster is ok (locally, should be) then its not logical why he goes amok. But since problems only happen when its disconected from network, it seems he wants some information from internet. I would really suggest to you to check with a screen what is being sent over rostopics. Sadly I have no other idea...

Comment: sadly, connecting it to a monitor makes the robot pretty unmovable because of the cable and we dont have any others currently at my workspace. but thanks for your help!